# julia angle function returns different values for same angle

Tags: julia

While using the function angle I came across this result:

```
julia> angle(-1+im*0.0)
3.141592653589793

julia> angle(-1-im*0.0)
-3.141592653589793
```

which is not properly wrong, but perhaps could cause discomfort because
usually the evaluation of the angle is in the interval `(-pi,pi]`.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @AlexanderMorley For the arguments in question: `-1-im*0.0 == -1+im*0.0` is true but `-1-im*0.0 === -1+im*0.0` is false. This is an artifact of `0.0 !== -0.0`. Definitely discomforting and perhaps an issue for `angle` can be filed. For other real types this doesn't happen e.g. `angle(-1-im*0)==angle(-1+im*0)`. The same happens for `log` which is equivalent to `angle` somewhat.

Comment: the problem is `float(-0) => 0.0`, but `float(-0.0)=>-0.0`.

Comment: This is probably not the venue for this discussion. The proper solution IMHO is to create another GenericFloat64 type which would be clean without IEEE 754 additions (NaNs, Infs etc.)

Comment: Integers don't have -0 but floats do, so that should not be surprising.

Comment: Some Matlab users like me may feel this strange, should we mention it in the [noteworthy differences](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/noteworthy-differences.html#Noteworthy-differences-from-MATLAB-1)?

Comment: Indeed what I meant to say that this isn't really a SO-type question. Agree @user2820579 you could raise an issue on github or discuss if there isn't already one for this (but I think there is...) or discuss on mailing list :)

Comment: Both of the reported values are correctly in the range (-pi, pi]. You may want to read up a bit on floating point arithmetic.

Comment: This seems like a perfectly reasonable question to me. The answer is subtle and, while it's not specific to Julia, it's fair for it to come up in the context of using Julia.

Answer (score 8):

This is correct and intentional. You are encountering what is known as a ["branch cut"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_point#Branch_cuts): a point where a multi-valued function has to choose between multiple values it could return. John D. Cook has a [short but good article](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2016/12/17/branch-cuts-and-common-lisp/) introducing the concept and outlining how Common Lisp approaches the problem of defining various branch cuts for various related functions consistently.

In the case of the `angle` function applied to the point -1 in the complex plane, any odd multiple of π is theoretically a correct answer. Angle values are normalized to be in the range [-π, π], however, which leaves only two odd multiples of π to choose between: ±π. Which one should be returned at -1 in the complex plane? In some sense, the question is "Which way did you approach the real line from?" If you approach -1 from above in the complex plane, then π is the is the answer that respects continuity since the angle of values slightly above the real line are close to π. If you approached -1 from below, however, then -π is the continuous answer since angles just below the real line are close -π. Accordingly, when we evaluate `angle` near -1 the sign of the imaginary part is significant – even if its value is zero (`±0.0`) – so we give different answers for `-1 ± 0.0im`:

- `angle(-1 + 0.0im) == +3.141592653589793`
- `angle(-1 - 0.0im) == -3.141592653589793`

These answers respect the continuity of `angle` with respect to the sign of the imaginary part of the argument. Many complex functions have similar branch cuts on the real line with different results depending on the sign of the zero-valued imaginary part of their argument.